# Disable Redirect On Registration Form submission Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I Have a registration form on my wordpress page with Theme my login, and I have the following jQuery code in the page `$('#test').click(function(){window.location = 'yay.html'});` with the purpose of taking them to a particular page on form submission. But the form appears to be overriding it and taking them a wordpress login page at `myurl.com/login/?checkemail=registered`, I need to disable this automatic redirect. I am aware that there are much easier was to redirect on form submission, but for other reason's I am unable to change the actual form code its self, I need to use Jquery that can be implemented don a page by page basis.

Comment: can you share jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filter to change the redirection page. I think is better use just wp_insert_user function and a ajax form. But you can also use what i said...

```
function __my_registration_redirect()
{
    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );
```

**SOURCE:** https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19692/how-to-redirect-a-sucessful-registration-to-a-page-template

Comment: It looks like that will work, there is an extra layer of issues, but that is for another post. thank you :)

Comment: now the issue I have is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782009/why-is-my-if-statement-defaulting-to-the-else-option-wordpress maybe you can shed some light on that as you are clearly a genius