# Why is my if statement defaulting to the else option - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I Have the following code:

```
if (is_page('541')){
    function __my_registration_redirect(){
        return home_url( '/affiliates-access/' );
    }
    add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );

}else if(is_page('1119')){
    function __my_registration_redirect(){
        return home_url( '/equinox-apartments/' );
    }
    add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );
}else{
    function __my_registration_redirect(){
        return home_url( '/' );
    }
    add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );
}
```

its suppose to detect the page that the form is submitted on and redirrect to a different page accordingly, but is always going to the `else` statement.... why? I cannot work it out. It seems like it should make sence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be like this:

```
function __my_registration_redirect() {

    if ( is_page('541') )  return home_url( '/affiliates-access/' );
    else if ( is_page('1119') ) return home_url( '/equinox-apartments/' );
    else return home_url( '/' );

}
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );
```

Comment: thanks @jogesh_pi I knew with stack overflow's help I would get there today... its been a long day hahah

Comment: I think is too late D:

Comment: thanks for trying @IagoMelanias it took about 4 posts on stack overflow today to finally come up with a solutions both you and jogesh_pi have been a huge help and have saved my bacon plus taught me a lot, I really appreciate both of your time.

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions It is the best approach, if you want to be a good programmer: Read First about WordPress, Then search and if you stuck in codes then COME HERE. This is basic approach that we can't use if else conditions for hooks, but we can use conditions with attached function.

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions Thanks, glad to help you :) Its a nice platform here to share knowledge and learn more and more.

Comment: Agree. I only learned how to do something on Wordpress when i stopped to search solutions to my problems and started to understand the Wordpress operations. When you get the code that solve your problem by another person, you lost the chance to get so much experience.